# VSTO Tools: Office 2010 to 2013 upgrade

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vsto

I'm working on a VSTO tools project for Excel. I'm now in the process of upgrading my machine.
My "old" laptop was running Windows 7 x64 with Office 2010 and Visual Studio 2012. My new machine has Windows 8 x64 with Office 2013 and Visual Studio 2012.

When opening my solution on VS2012, in the new machine, it gives me an error loading the project:

> Cannot create the project because the application associated with this
>   project type is not installed on this computer. You must install the
>   Microsoft Office application that is associated with this project
>   type.

I reckon this is due to the Office Upgrade. I don't want to come back to Office 2010 unless it's really necessary.

Do you have any suggestion?

Best regards,
jpsfs

Comment: I don't think you have many options - a VSTO project created on a machine with Office 2010 will only work (for development) on a machine with Office 2010 (same with Office 2013). Either install Office 2010 on your new Windows 8 machine, manually transfer your project into a new Office 2013 VSTO project, or set up a VM with Office 2010 on it to be used for development.

Comment: Can't you install the VSTO/PIOs for Office 2010 to get around this?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this?  Adding the PIOs seemed to only make my life worse.

Comment: That's not true -- In Visual Studio 2010/Office 2013 you could do a registry hack and run / debug a Word 2010 / VSTO 4.0 add-in against Word 2013. -- But with Visual Studio 2013, it's trying to force me to upgrade the project.  This is awful.

Comment: I should note (as maybe it's helpful to the poster) I'm running VS 2013, Update 3 -- and it's like really adamant about upgrading the project on the Office 2013 machines -- I'm trying to figure out how to make it not do that... -- but maybe it's what you want? (Maybe even just upgrade the project in VS 2013, and then go back to working in VS2012 from there?)

Comment: I figured out my issue -- it lets me work with an Office 2010 solution on a box with Office 2010 or Office 2013 installed (on VS 2013 update 3) -- I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**My Solution**

Okay, so after a lot of banging my head against the wall -- finding out the msbuild properties, conditions, and project inlcudes don't work for/in the ProjectExtensions section, I figured out an additional hack that makes my .csproj work in Visual Studio 2013 [Update 3] whether the developer has Office 2010 or Office 2013 installed (it's detailed in the second bullet point below -- which is not required for the same behavior in VS 2010, YMMV for VS 2012).

To make your project work this way you need to do these *three* things:

- Hand edit your .csproj file and find all the office interop assembly references -- make sure the version is set to version "14.0.0.0" (as opposed to "15.0.0.0") and that the "SpecificVersion" child element is present and set to "False".
- Under the Project\ProjectExtensions\VisualStudio\FlavorProperties\ProjectProperties element find the "OfficeVersion" attribute/value pair and remove it (so the attribute that reads `OfficeVersion="14.0"` -- delete that). -- Leave all other 14.0s intact, if anything got changed to 15.0, downgrade it back to 14.0 (and again, if it's a reference, set SpecificVersion to false). -- Do not worry about changing any GUIDs, just leave them as they are!
- At this point, the solution will open and compile on machines that are running Visual Studio 2013 whether they have Office 2010 or Office 2013. -- But it will not *start* the solution on machines running Office 2013.  To fix that:

  - Open regedit and navigate to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\
  - Export the entire 15.0 branch to a .reg file.
  - Open the file in notepad and change all registry path occurrences of "15.0" to "14.0".
  - Re-save the file (make sure you save it as unicode).
  - Import the file & restart Visual Studio. -- This will allow you to start with debugging with Office 2013.

One other thing to keep in mind -- especially if you use EmbedInteropTypes, make sure that when you do your release / publish build that you do it from a machine with Office 2010 (and not 2013) installed, so that the published assembly is built against the Office 2010 specific libraries. -- This will maintain that you have backward and forward compatibility between the two versions.

Again, this worked for me for a Word Add-in -- For an Excel Add-in YMMV.

**Original "Answer" (may contain useful details for others)**

I mentioned in comments above that I'm having the opposite problem -- VS 2013 Update 3 is forcibly upgrading my projects if the user has Office 2013 installed.

You can try installing VS 2013 Update 3 (even temporarily, say in a VM) and the latest VSTO 2012 / 2013 version, and opening the project, it should forcibly upgrade yours as well.  I know you're using Excel, and I'm using Word, but the section it's upgrading:

**Old .csproj XML:**

```
<Project ...>
  ...
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}">
        <ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="{20A848B8-E01F-4801-962E-25DB0FF57389}" OfficeVersion="14.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/w" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
        <Host Name="Word"... />
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  ...
</Project>
```

**New .csproj XML:**

```
<Project ...>
  ...
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}">
        <ProjectProperties HostName="Word" HostPackage="{29A7B9D7-A7F1-4328-8EF0-6B2D1A56B2C1}" OfficeVersion="15.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Word" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\InstallRoot\Path#WINWORD.EXE" DebugInfoCommandLine="/w" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{51063C3A-E220-4D12-8922-BDA915ACD783}" />
        <Host Name="Word"... />
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  ...
</Project>
```

Looks to me like the two things that changed are:

- The registry path from 14.0 to 15.0 (which in VS 2010 was easy to work around -- you just created a matching 14.0 registry path that pointed to where you installed Word 2013 and it worked fine).
- The host package's CLS ID.  I don't know what they are for Excel, but you can probably look them up. -- I prefer not to change the CLS ID of the checked in project, such that developers developing & testing the project against Word 2010 can continue to do so, as well as those developing and testing against Word 2013.

Of additional note it looks like two references got updated from 14.0 to 15.0 as well -- this is a major no-no -- since we want to only build against/embed the 2010 Interop Types (these work fine in 2013, but we don't want to accidentally access some 2013 only property and then have it not work in 2010...)

The two references that got updated are "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" and "Office".

**Edit:**
Looks like I can set those two references to SpecificVersion: False, and then hand edit the XML file to step them back down to "14.0.0.0" (version seems to be grayed out from the regular menu).

Comment: This just saved my day - thank you! I have a setup with both Office 2010 and Office 2013 installed, and still had to remove the OfficeVersion=14 attribute to stop Visual Studio from forcing an update to Office 2013.

Comment: This is great. It would be better in your answer if you gave an example of the SpecificVersion child element (it's not present in my .vbproj file and I'm not sure of its format).

Comment: I think this doesn't work anymore in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, at least not on my Windows 8.1 64-bit machine with Office 2013. I can't get rid anymore of the `error  : Cannot create the project because the application associated with this project type is not installed on this computer. You must install the Microsoft Office application that is associated with this project type.`

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I can't speak for VBProj, but it's msbuild, so specific version should be present if you've set it.  If it's not present, it's because you did not set it. -- if you set it in the reference properties, then it should appear in the XML. -- Regarding update 4, was it working before you upgraded to update 4? -- Or were you just never able to get it working?

Comment: @brainslug83 yes, it was working well before updating VS. I even went back in my svn repo to a working version with no luck. I don't have the energy to revert my VS install to validate my hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to this one - I had the same issue trying to create a word document project in VS 2013 from and existing 2010 word project.

My fix was to use an earlier .net framework version (version 4 instead of version 4.5). When I selected this in the project creation wizard I get options to select Office 2010 apps

I'm a noob to .net but seems to be working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

From the VS menu select:
Project
 Properties
Debug

Change Start Action to  Start external program
Enter the address of the Excel.exe

Something like  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE

Comment: Dude, he can't open the project... this is not helpful.

Comment: If you can open the project and get a `You cannot debug or run this project, because the required version of the Microsoft Office application is not installed.` error, this might help.

Comment: Maybe.  It might break other things though (I believe doing this will change properties in the .csproj which may screw up building against 2010, etc.) -- the registry thing (from my answer above) might be a lame hack, but it doesn't change anything in the .csproj, so, you're free to still develop and test against both versions.