# Can't find Word 2010 Document template in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, templates, visual-studio-2013, ms-word, vsto

I have VS 2013 installed and Microsoft Office 2010 and I want to create a new project using Word 2010 document as my template, but I don't see the option for this version.  Only Word 2013 Document template is available, but since I don't have it installed I get an error `Cannot create project because the application associated with this project type is not installed on this computer.  You must install the Microsoft Office application that is associated with this project type.`  Can I use a 2010 Word template, if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the very helpful answer in the below link:

[VSTO Tools: Office 2010 to 2013 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783931/vsto-tools-office-2010-to-2013-upgrade)

I think you can try only one of the points mentioned in the answer:

> Under the
>   Project\ProjectExtensions\VisualStudio\FlavorProperties\ProjectProperties
>   element find the "OfficeVersion" attribute/value pair and remove it
>   (so the attribute that reads OfficeVersion="14.0" -- delete that). --
>   Leave all other 14.0s intact, if anything got changed to 15.0,
>   downgrade it back to 14.0 (and again, if it's a reference, set
>   SpecificVersion to false). -- Do not worry about changing any GUIDs,
>   just leave them as they are!

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I just upgraded my version of office to 2013 ;-)